# IOS setting a custom delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I'm working through the IOS HelloWorld example and I have a question regarding setting the delegate for a TextField. In the example it was as easy as control-dragging from the TextField to the ViewController. But now say I wanted to create a custom class to act as my delegate as so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SweetAssDelegate : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField;
@end

#import "SweetAssDelegate.h"

@implementation SweetAssDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    NSLog(@"Calling Delegate");
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

How can I set this class to be the delegate of the TextField? As far as I can tell there is not way to accomplish this through the GUI. I tried manually setting the delegation after window load with no success:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SweetAssDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputField;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SweetAssDelegate *foo = [[SweetAssDelegate alloc] init];
    [self.inputField setDelegate:foo];

    NSLog(@"Delegate: %@", self.inputField.delegate);
}
```

I actually receive some sort of memory exception when bringing up the keyboard? Any ideas? Thanks.

As a side question, where should I always use viewDidLoad to initialize any variables? I noticed that init was not being called???

Comment: What kind of memory exception?

Comment: There should be no need to declare `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField;` in the interface of `SweetAssDelegate` as it is already declared in `UITextFieldDelegate`, which your class implements.

Answer (score 2):

Your delegate object, `foo`, is allowed to fall out of scope and is released at the end of `viewDidLoad` and by the time the keyboard comes up, it doesn't exist anymore. Make it an ivar (or property) of your view controller, or otherwise make sure that `foo` doesn't fall out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Thus, it could be something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SweetAssDelegate *foo;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.foo = [[SweetAssDelegate alloc] init];
    [self.inputField setDelegate:self.foo];

    NSLog(@"Delegate: %@", self.inputField.delegate);
}
```

Comment: He's better off with a property.

Comment: @SimonGermain I don't particularly care if he defines the ivar himself, or let's a property synthesize it for him. The key is that he just needs something with a scope of the view controller, not of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: ivars aren't "cool" anymore, but +1 cuz you get the point! :P

Comment: Before ARC I would need to use retain correct? Now that I am using ARC property's are the way to go?

Comment: @user1437801 I have a slightly different spin on this: The key issue is that it shouldn't be a local variable of `viewDidLoad`. And if MRC, if the local variable was retained (and no `retain` is needed because it already would have a +1 `retainCount`), you'll fix the crash, but you'll leak. In terms of whether this should be a instance variable (ivar) or a property in this particular situation, I'll leave to others to debate. Just make sure it shares the scope of the view controller, not of `viewDidLoad`. But ARC is definitely the way to go!

Comment: Is this (overriding viewDidLoad) the preferred way of setting up/initializing objects in a view? Is there a better way?

Comment: @user1437801 Yes, `viewDidLoad` is the logical place to programmatically set up and initialize objects in a view. Clearly, when you use a storyboard and/or NIB, you can design much of your user interface, which often is easier than doing it programmatically. And there are portions of user interface configuration belong in special methods (e.g. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` for sophisticated user interface rotation changes, table view data source delegate methods for configuring table views, etc), but `viewDidLoad` does much of the basic view configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your textfield delegate must have the  implemented to be your textfield delegate I guess.

A delegate manages the communication between objects, which means your custom delegate must allow communication between objects and must provide methods, the textfield can work with...

Another example is a tableView:

You can make a custom delegate which implements the  delegates and then calls some tableview related Methods...

Here this code might be interesting for you:

```
@interface myCustomDelegateForTextFields <UITextFieldDelegate>


@end

@implementation myCustomDelegateForTextFields 

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

return TRUE;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController 


myCustomDelegateForTextFields *txtfielddelegate = [[myCustomDelegateForTextFields alloc] init];

UITextField *whatever;
whatever.delegate = txtfielddelegate;

//your textfield now listens to the BOOL method in your custom delegate

@end
```

Is it that what u were looking for? :)

you can ofc pack the myCustomDelegateForTextField delegate in another class and call the class

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem, because you've defined your delegate object within the implementation, too, and `txtfielddelegate` will fall out of scope. The delegate object needs to be part of the `@interface` of the view controller, (either the main interface or a private class extension) not the `@implementation`. I'm sure you were just trying to use shorthand here and you probably meant it to be an ivar/property of the view controller, but it seems it's an important point given that this is why his program is crashing.